# Find CDF and PDF of circle area

Tags: probability

Radius of circle, represented as a random variable $R$, has probability distribution $R:U(a,b), a,b>0$. Find CDF and PDF for the area $Y$ of circle?

I know that for some t, when $t\leq a^2\pi, F_Y(t)=0. $  When I am working in this interval $a^2t<t\leq b^2t $ I don't know how to compute $F_Y(t)=P(Y<t)=P(R^2\pi<t)$, now this part from the solutions I don't understand $P(a<R<\sqrt{\frac{t}{\pi}})=\frac{\sqrt{\frac{t}{\pi}}-a}{b-a} $ .  Also when $t>b^2\pi, F_Y(t)=1.$

And for the PDF all I need to do is find the derivative of CDF.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have $Y=\pi X^2$ and thus for $y\in(\pi a^2,\pi b^2)$
$$F_Y(y)=P(Y\leq y)=P(\pi X^2\leq y)=P\left(X\leq\sqrt{\frac{y}{\pi}}\right)=F_X\left(\sqrt{\frac{y}{\pi}}\right)=\dots$$

Comment: I edited the post, in solutions they wrote $P(a<R<\sqrt{\frac{t}{\pi}})$, why did they write $a<R$, is it because it is the lower limit and how to compute the rest?

Comment: @untitled Well since $P(R\leq a)=0$ we have $P(a<R<\sqrt{\frac{t}{\pi}})=P(R<\sqrt{\frac{t}{\pi}})$. So both are equivalent.

Comment: Sorry for bothering, one last thing I don't see how is the solution $\frac{\sqrt{\frac{t}{\pi}}-a}{b-a}$

Comment: The CDF for $X$ is $F_X(x)=\int_a^x \frac{1}{b-a}dt=\frac{x-a}{b-a}$ when $x\in (a,b)$. So as derived above the CDF for $Y$ at $t$ is then $F_X(\sqrt{t/\pi})$ which is the expression that you wrote